# How to simulate or change the GROUP BY in an SPARQL Query?

Tags: sparql, rdf, rdfs

I have executed successfully this query in [D2RQ](http://d2rq.org/), but, since performance problems I'm using now [Ontop](http://ontop.inf.unibz.it/) which performs faster but it [does not support aggregated functions](https://github.com/ontop/ontop/issues/109) like `GROUP BY`, which in the case of this query is key to get the desired results. 
Any idea how can I do a similar query without using the `GROUP BY`?

```
PREFIX d2r: <http://sites.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/suhl/bizer/d2r-server/config.rdf#>
PREFIX v: <http://www.vocab.com/resource/vocab/>

SELECT ?hour ((?latest - ?earliest) as ?value) {
{ 
SELECT ?hour (MIN(?value) as ?earliest) WHERE {
   ?s v:time ?time;
   v:value ?value
}
GROUP BY (HOURS(?time) as ?hour)
}

{ SELECT ?hour (MAX(?value) as ?latest) WHERE {
   ?s v:time ?time;
      v:value ?value
}
GROUP BY (HOURS(?time) as ?hour) 
}
  FILTER (?hour>= timeFrom && ?hour <= timeTo)
}
ORDER BY ?hour
```

Comment: You can't "simulate" aggregation especially not without having the GROUP BY feature. What about using other implementations like Apache Jena or other triple stores?

Comment: Having a Database-to-RDF tool is a requirement for this problem, triples stores are not.

Comment: So you need to look at other RDB2RDF implementations that support aggregation, like [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/features-comparison-matrix/) (from [my employer](http://www.openlinksw.com/))...